# using interactive elements inside a bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am successfully using a bootstrap popover on a link click. I have some form elements inside the popover: a textfield, checkbox and a button. I'm able to attach a button listener using jquery.live(), but inside that button listener I don't seem to have any access to the correct form elements. They exist if I trace them out in a console log, but their values always remain the original defaults, so if I go $('#txtComment').val(); the string is always the same, regardless of what I put into the field.

Are there any examples, tutorials or source code I could look at of something that is using any kind of interactivity inside a bootstrap popover?

this is how I'm setting up the popover:

```
this.commentLink.popover({
  trigger: 'manual',
  placement: 'right',
  html : true,
  content: function () {
    return $('#commentPopout').html();
  }
}).popover('hide');

//jquery.on won't work here so we use live
$('#btnSubmitComment').live('click', this.proxy(this.commentSubmitClick));
```

then I'm doing this to successfully show it:

```
this.commentLink.popover('show');
```

and this is the button click function:

```
commentSubmitClick: function(e){
  console.log($('#txtComment').val());//always shows default text regardless of what I've actually typed in the field
}
```

Comment: Dude, you made my day! I'm at least 2 hours trying to get value from popover. And your solution works great. Thanks man!

Comment: In case you need the state of HTML attributes preserved, see this git issue: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4097

Answer (score 19):

The syntax changed. The answer of [Kalin C Ringkvist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10885738/675065) needs to be slightly modified:

```
var popover = this.commentLink.data('popover').tip();
```

Note the method `tip()` instead of `$tip`.

Comment: As of Bootstrap 3.0, the syntax is `this.commentLink.data("bs.popover").$tip`

Answer (score 15):

Yay! figured it out. Why, oh why is this not documented? I miss working in actionscript.

```
var popover = this.commentLink.data('popover').$tip;
var comment = popover.find('#txtComment').val();//gives correct string
```

This code must be run while the popover is actually visible, since the elements don't exist when it's not visible.

-Oh, and using jquery.live() is deprecated, but you can use this $tip variable to get the button reference instead once the popover is created.

Answer (score 1):

For a variable number of buttons/links that have events binded, here's how I did it (going off what's been answered previously):

```
var list = $('<ul/>');
myCollections.items.each(function(item){
    var row = $('<li/>');
    row.append(item.get('id')));
    row.append($('<a/>').addClass('delete').html('remove'));
    list.append(row);
});

$(this.el).find('a').popover({ content: list }).on('click', function(){
    var popover = $(this).data('popover').tip();
    $(popover).find('.delete').on('click', removeitem);
});

function removeitem(){ // code to remove the item here }

// The HTML (in the popover) would look like this:
<ul>
    <li>1<a class="delete">remove</a></li>
    <li>2<a class="delete">remove</a></li>
    <li>3<a class="delete">remove</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey I don't really understand what u did. How does it look in html?

Answer (score 0):

I used another trick to be able to attach functions to the elements in the popover. I just added another click listener on the element that displays the popover. In the click listener a function with some timeout is started (for example 500 milliseconds). After the function is started, you should be able to access your popover elements. Here is the code:

```
        <!-------- HTML ----------->
        <a class="btn" id="popover_btn">show popover</a>

        /******* JAVASCRIPT *******/
        $('#popover_btn').popover({
            html: true,
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'click',
            title: 'add new value',
            content: '<input id="ttt" type="text"/>'
        });

        $('#popover_btn').click(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                // here you can write your "ON SHOW" code
                console.debug($('#ttt').length);        // Outputs 1 - the element is there
            }, 500);
        });
```